# Plotly Histogram Retains Ghost Categorical X Values

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have data with fifty various categorical values in a column labelled "cat", and a second column with a continuous numerical value "amount".  I only want to plot the subset of "cat" with an "amount" greater than 5.  Why do I have the ghost-label on my x-axis for those intermediate rows that should be omitted based on my subset?

Example code:

```
cat<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
amount<-c(4,15,18,2,9)

df<-data.frame(cat=cat,amount=amount)

df1<-subset(df,amount >5)

library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(df1, x = ~cat, y = ~amount) 
p
```

df1 printed out:

```
  cat  amount
2  b   15
3  c   18
5  e    9
```

And the plot generated:
[image: Erroneous Plot]
It is interesting that "a" doesn't appear on my x axis, but "d" does.  I take it there is something going on with the row numbers, but why is this and how can I prevent this from happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you. I see the five levels there, is there a best practice for removing the unwanted levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subset` does not drop the unused levels of a factor as shown below

```
str(df1)
 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ cat   : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 2 3 5
 $ amount: num  15 18 9
```

So `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` will import `cat` as a character vector which you can modify to factor after subsetting or use it directly.

```
df <- data.frame(cat=cat,amount=amount, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1 <- subset(df,amount >5)
plot_ly(df1, x = ~cat, y = ~amount)
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer.  Your answer fixes the problem well.  In my case, I was bringing columns in from elsewhere and had to use `as.character()` on the existing factors data (which I discovered using `sapply(df1,class)`).  Thank you!